# when the render is happening inside the onsubmit handler

Tags: reactjs, state

i am new to react, During the learning i tried some code to understand controlled and uncontrolled components , i used both usestate and useref.for first time i given a data name as:john and age:40 and click submit , i see name as "prakash" and age as 40 because i change the state during submit, then i changed only the age as 60 and click submit , it doest not change the age , i am so wonder because i change the state during sumbit which means it need to render and change the age into 60.can you please explain why it not changed the age?

```
import { Fragment, useReducer, useRef, useState } from "react"



export default function Sample()
{
    
    const [name,setname]=useState();
    const age=useRef();
    const handelsubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setname("prakash")
        console.log(`${name},${age.current.value}`)
    }
    return(
    <form onSubmit={handelsubmit}>
        <label>name:{name}</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setname(e.target.value)} />
        <label>age:{age.current?.value==undefined?null:age.current.value}</label>
        <input type="text" ref={age}/>
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why changing the age input value did not update the displayed value of age is because you're using a **useRef** hook to access the value of the age input field, which **does not trigger a re-render** when its value changes.

In your code, you're updating the state of name when the form is submitted, but you're not updating the state of age. When you access the value of age using age.current.value, you're directly accessing the current value of the age input field without using the state of the component. Since the value of age.current.value is not part of the component's state, changing it does not trigger a re-render.

You can update the state of age in the **handelsubmit** function after setting the state of **name**:

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [age, setAge] = useState("");
const ageRef = useRef();

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setName("prakash");
  setAge(ageRef.current.value);
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <label>name: {name}</label>
    <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
    <label>age: {age}</label>
    <input type="text" ref={ageRef} />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
);
```